# Minimal number of transmitters - task with graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, min

We have got described an office. It consists of rooms and passages between them. There is `n` rooms (numbered `1-n`) and `n-1` passages. We have got description of every passage - 2 numbers which are numbers of rooms that are connected with this passage. We can get to every other room from all rooms in office.

We need to place minimal number of transmitters, so that there is a connection in every passage. The connection will be in given passage if:

- there is a transmitter in one of the rooms that are at the end of this passage
  OR
- there are 2 or more transmitters in area of all rooms that are accessible via any 1 passage (max length is 1 passage) from rooms that are at the end of this passage

We can place as many transmitters in one room as we need to.

What are possible solution for this? Any algorithms or example codes? Maybe similar tasks?

I thought about dividing this graph at its ends and put transmitters possibly nearest to center. How about this?

Comment: It helps us a lot to see your code, for us to be able to answer as precise and correct as possible. If attacking the "minimal number" is a problem, first solve it the brute force way, almost guaranteed to be the maximal number. Therefrom you/we can start working on optimizing it.

Comment: @Emz Writing it with brute-force way isn't rather any problem. Pure brute-force would be O(n^3) where each room has 0,1 or 2 transmitters and then we are checking for connection in every passage of course with some small optimizations. Did you mean _almost guaranteed to be the maximal  or minimal_?

Comment: Maximal. Thing is, this site isn't really dedicated to providing examples or writing code for you, but to answer specific questions. Without at least a brute-force example I doubt there will be too many answers.

Comment: Yes, but I am mostly asking about algorithm or similar problem with well-known solutions.